Resources on Rietveld Refinement
I have been recently getting into FullProf Suite to analyze diffraction data and perform Rietveld Refinement on my data. I got into it mainly because it is a free software and commonly recommended, but whenever I have talked about the software with my peers they all seem to have the same complaint: the fact it has a lot of customization means it is easy to over-parametrize your data or making fitting choices which significantly alter your results, make it feel unreliable - as if you can make any number of choices to make the program get you the outcome you intend, rather than the most consistent results.
Given the amount of versatility in the software, I am curious as to what resources you would recommend for people starting to do Rietveld Refinement. I am particularly interested in articles/books that can give a walkthrough not of the software itself but of, for example, when to chose between a 6-coefficient background fit vs a 24-coefficient one, so you don't fall into over-parametrization traps while still getting reliable, well refined results.
What is your go-to manual on XRD refinement techniques?

"the fact it has a lot of customization means it is easy to over-parametrize your data or making fitting choices which significantly alter your results". If your refined parameters (for instance, lattice parameters) remarkably change as the number of refined parameters increases, the problem is the quality of your diffraction data.
Over-parametrization depends on the quality of the data in your pattern. This is the starting point. You must verify the quality of your data, that is, if you collected your data with a proper scan step, range and time-step. If your pattern was obtained using a fast scan and/or a limited angular range (= limited number of diffraction peaks), these data are not reliable for refinement.
Depending on the quality of your data collection (and also of your sample) you can reliably refine structural (lattice parameters, atomic position) and microstructural (size and/or strain) parameters. Experience makes a lot!
You can consult:
"Rietveld refinement guidelines" https://journals.iucr.org/j/issues/1999/01/00/gl0561/index.html
"The Rietveld method" (IUCr Mono-graph on Crystallography, No. 5.), Edited by R. A. Young.  Oxford: International Union of Crystallography/Oxford University
Press, 1993. ISBN 0-19-855577-6
"Rietveld Refinement: Practical Powder Diffraction Pattern Analysis Using Topas"
Dinnebier, Robert E.; Leineweber, Andreas; Evans, John S. O.;  ISBN 10: 3110456214 ISBN 13: 9783110456219
